# Query keeps showing all records instead of a criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a very simple Select query in access. I have created a report from the query, where there are two date fields on the form for the user to fill and then a button to preview that report. But it keeps showing all of the records instead of showing only the ones within the range. What might be wrong with the query?

[image]

```
SELECT Marketics.Agent, Marketics.[Policy Number], Marketics.[Policy Status], Marketics.Decision, Marketics.[Old Premium], Marketics.[New Premium], Marketics.Difference, Marketics.Case
FROM Marketics
WHERE [Marketics].[Date Completed]>=[forms]![Policies Worked]![from]<=[forms]![Policies Worked]![to];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM Marketics
WHERE [Date Completed] >= [forms]![Policies Worked]![from] AND [Date Completed] <= [forms]![Policies Worked]![to]
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM Marketics
WHERE [Date Completed] BETWEEN [forms]![Policies Worked]![from] AND [forms]![Policies Worked]![to]
```